# livereload with npm and browserify

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify, livereload

I am trying to use just npm for building my project (so i dont want to use gulp or grunt).

I want to reload the page everytime any project files change, but i can't figure out how this can be done. Can somebody help me, how i would need to use e.g livereload for this example?:

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "browserify js/index.js > build/index.js -vd",
    "start": "watchify js/index.js -o build/index.js -vd & serve . -p 3001 & opener http://localhost:3000"
  }
```

Thanks!
rowa

Comment: This looks interesting: https://github.com/milankinen/livereactload

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-browserify#toc-live-rebuild